# Image as page title does not align vertically with header buttons

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

In a jQuery Mobile page, I need an header with a "back" button, a centered image as the page title and a right button that is ideed a square image.
Both images have the same height.

I likely managed to get what I want with the following code:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x35/096/fff.png" class="ui-title"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35/096/fff.png" class="ui-btn-right"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **[Live jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/7g7n0zf4/)**

but it seems the three elements in the header do not properly align vertically.

This is the vertical alignment I'd like to achieve:

[image: vertical alignment mockup]

Many thanks!

Comment: There's 0 css in the fiddle you have provided.

Comment: I fixed the link to the fiddle. I tagged the question with `css` because I believe the solution lies in finding the right classes and/or custom styles to style the header's elements.

Comment: @ajmajmajma As can be seen in the fiddle, jQuery mobile stylesheet is embedded.

Comment: It's the Jquery Mobile stylings that are causing the problem. At least one of the elements is positioned absolutely....so there will be a **lot** of tweakingt o be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To vertical align elements, It can be very easy to use `inline-block`.

```css
a, img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

a {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext"></a>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x35/096/fff.png" class="ui-title"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35/096/fff.png" class="ui-btn-right"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

To make it work with the jQuery Mobile style, you'll have to overwrite some default rules. the left and right buttons are being set as absolute position, so we can use css `transform` to make them always vertically middle aligned *(works for any/unknown height)*. See the demo as follows.

```
.ui-title {
    display: inline-block !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
}
.ui-btn-left,
.ui-btn-right {
    top: 50% !important;
    transform: translateY(-50%) !important;
}
```

**Fiddle Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/nzd31v9o/

Comment: How does this override jQuery mobile's stylesheet?

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't seem to work with jQuery Mobile's stylesheet, neither declaring the rules as `!important`

Comment: @etuardu added solution for jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Thank you, the second snippet seems to show a rather good solution.
I edited the css using `img.ui-title` instead of `.ui-title` because it was breaking the horizontal alignment for text headers though.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to add the ui-title class to the right button, and then for the back button, simply set the top position and height:

```
<div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header">
        <a class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext "></a>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/120x35/096/fff.png" class="ui-title"/>
        <img src="http://placehold.it/35x35/096/fff.png" class="ui-btn-right ui-title" />
    </div>
</div>

.ui-btn-left {
    top: 0.7em !important;
    height: 35px;
}
```

> **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7g7n0zf4/1/)**

If you prefer to keep the back button smaller and centered:

```
.ui-btn-left {
    top: 0.7em !important;
    margin-top: 2.5px !important;    
}
```

> **[DEMO 2](https://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/7g7n0zf4/3/)**